# "return this" from mixins

Tags: groovy, mixins

When adding a runtime mixin, `return this` returns the type of the mixin, not the class that has been mixed into, and even setting the return type of the method won't force conversion, but instead throw an error. How can I do `return this` from a mixin method?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `metaClass.owner` instead of `this`.